# Check whether public address was derived from a private key

Tags: metamask, addresses, private-key, public-key

I have several ETH accounts (and I own a private key from each one of them). I also have an address with a public key (holding some funds of course) but I totally forgot where this address came from. Is it possible to check whether an address was derived from a concrete private key? And if so, is there a way how to tell the derivation path by which the public address was created so I can get in control of my funds back again?

Comment: You can use this tool to derive addresses from private keys https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ - it is super technical though and needs understanding how Ethereum keys work. There is also several legacy standards on these.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Cool, I'll try it. However, how do I compare 0x address to the address in the following format `1GmdUsd1ov2CAf6wP4EEJkQL5E1FXYDeWJ`?

Comment: That is a Bitcoin address. I am not sure if bip39 can crank out Ethereum address format out from the box.

Comment: Another tool is that you just import your seeds to mycrypto.com or myetherwallet.com